# A function that will remove HTML <div> and </div> tags from a string?

Tags: plugin-development, forms, html

I *need* a function that I can use that will remove <div> and </div> tags from a string. I have tried *esc_attr()*, and even *wp_strip_all_tags()* --- none of them work. They all leave the <div> and </div> tags in the string - which causes certain social-media buttons to turn out in ways that *really* do not look good.

Any suggestions what to do?

Comment: Can you show us how are you using `wp_strip_all_tags()` and it is not stripping `<div>`?

Answer (score 1):

Use a PHP function to do this: https://php.net/strip_tags

example:

```
echo strip_tags("<div>my text</div>");
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's only  <div></div> I would do a [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/de/function.preg-replace.php), like this:

```
$string = preg_replace ( '|</?[^>]*>|i', '', $string );
```

This removes only the tags, not the text between the Tags. I understood this is what you wanted.